# How do I fix the low speed of Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter's ap0 in Debian?

Tags: wifi, internet, wifi-hotspot

Unlike Windows, I discovered that the speed of my Access Point is too slow about 50-70KB on Debian unlike Windows it is about 1.3MB which is the original full download speed of my connection.

Here are the interfaces I have:

> ```
> PHY     Interface       Driver          Chipset
>
>  phy0    ap0             ath9k           Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
>  phy0    wlan0           ath9k           Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
>  phy1    wlan1           rt2800usb       Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT30
> ```

Unlike Windows, since I cannot use `Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070` as AP and STA in the same time, I used `Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)` yet It is slow.

How do I tweak the speed?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same adapter build into my laptop. For me the solution was to disable a setting in my router (Telekom Speedport W724V)

Under the 2.4 GHz frequency band settings i unchecked the box "max. 300 Mbit/s". The manual states here:

> With the max. 300 Mbit/s option, you can increase your WiFi's speed by increasing the useable channel bandwidth from 20 MHz to 40 MHz.

I guess you should try reducing your access points bandwith to 20MHz.

Hope it helps.